# Obtain Keycloak access token from trusted client without user password

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, keycloak, openid-connect

We have a client that among other things creates and manages Keycloak accounts.

Would it be possible for that client to retrieve tokens on behalf of the users without having to create any user passwords at all? In fact, we'd like to create user accounts and not set a password to start with. None of these users will ever authenticate themselves.

None of the oauth2 flows seem to really match this, and we were wondering if there is a variation of the password grant type in which the password is not required for trusted client ID/Secret.

Some options we explored so far are offline tokens and user impersonation, but the former requires persisting secrets, and the latter relies upon proprietary Keycloak features using cookies rather than standard OIDC.

Comment: There isn't a oauth2 flow that works without passwords. Impersonization is your best bet and does NOT require cookies. Maybe this will work for you?https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#direct-naked-impersonation

Comment: Ohhh, that's right, we were not aware there was a cookie free alternative! Thanks for that, We also got some more insights in this blog post from Thomas Darimnont https://blog.softwaremill.com/who-am-i-keycloak-impersonation-api-bfe7acaf051a

Thank you very much @qdivision

Answer (score 0):

There's as of today an experimental oauth 2 token exchange grant type available in keycloak: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-19

As @qdivision pointed out: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#direct-naked-impersonation
And Thomas Darimont: https://blog.softwaremill.com/who-am-i-keycloak-impersonation-api-bfe7acaf051a